# Dev Containers: VS-Code Extension Receiving Segmentation Fault when opening Podman container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, containers, podman

I use to be able to run this one project with docker / docker-compose, but we've started switching to podman/podman-compose. I've been trying to open up a Container using Podman on my VS-Code using the Dev Containers extension and I'm getting the following error:

```
[11115 ms] 
[11115 ms] Start: Starting VS Code Server
[11116 ms] Start: Preparing Extensions
[11116 ms] Start: Run in container: test ! -f '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.installExtensionsMarker' && set -o noclobber && mkdir -p '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine' && { > '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.installExtensionsMarker' ; } 2> /dev/null
[11128 ms] 
[11129 ms] 
[11129 ms] Exit code 1
[11129 ms] Extensions cache, install extensions: None
[11129 ms] Start: Run in container: test -d /root/.vscode-server/extensionsCache && ls /root/.vscode-server/extensionsCache || true
[11140 ms] 
[11140 ms] 
[11140 ms] Start: Run in container: test -d /vscode/vscode-server/extensionsCache && ls /vscode/vscode-server/extensionsCache || true
[11149 ms] 
[11149 ms] 
[11149 ms] Extensions cache, link in container: None
[11149 ms] Optimizing extensions for quality: stable
[11149 ms] Start: Run in container: /root/.vscode-server/bin/6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794/bin
*
* Visual Studio Code Server
*
* By using the software, you agree to
* the Visual Studio Code Server License Terms (https://aka.ms/vscode-server-license) and
* the Microsoft Privacy Statement (https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-US/privacystatement).
*
[12922 ms] Server bound to 127.0.0.1:33077 (IPv4)
Extension host agent listening on 33077

[14020 ms] Container server: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[14064 ms] Error: unexpected end of parent stream
        at So.destroy (/Users/david.dsilva/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.304.0/dist/extension/extension.js:24:106773)
        at So.write (/Users/david.dsilva/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.304.0/dist/extension/extension.js:24:107514)
        at /Users/david.dsilva/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.304.0/dist/extension/extension.js:24:109617
        at /Users/david.dsilva/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.304.0/dist/extension/extension.js:24:95001
        at /Users/david.dsilva/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.304.0/dist/extension/extension.js:24:97674
        at Object.cb (/Users/david.dsilva/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.304.0/dist/extension/extension.js:24:104092)
        at c (/Users/david.dsilva/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.304.0/dist/extension/extension.js:24:102318)
        at /Users/david.dsilva/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.304.0/dist/extension/extension.js:24:102465
        at s (/Users/david.dsilva/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.304.0/dist/extension/extension.js:27:5371)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/david.dsilva/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.304.0/dist/extension/extension.js:27:5541)
        at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
        at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12)
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
[14065 ms] Container server terminated (code: 139, signal: null).
[15381 ms] Start: Run in container: echo 33077 >'/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.devport-6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794'
[15383 ms] userEnvProbe is taking longer than 2 seconds. Process not found.
[15399 ms] 
[15399 ms] 
[15400 ms] Start: Run in container: mkdir -p '/tmp/devcontainers-1b89834a-fb03-4bf3-ae06-650fb90e26e91692287263792' && cat > '/tmp/devcontainers-1b89834a-fb03-4bf3-ae06-650fb90e26e91692287263792/env-loginInteractiveShell.json' << 'envJSON'
[15400 ms] Port forwarding for container port 33077 starts listening on local port.
[15400 ms] Port forwarding local port 33077 to container port 33077
[15401 ms] Start: Run: /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin) --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node /Users/david.dsilva/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.304.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js run-user-commands --user-data-folder /Users/david.dsilva/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data --docker-path podman --docker-compose-path podman-compose --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-1b89834a-fb03-4bf3-ae06-650fb90e26e91692287263792 --workspace-folder /Users/david.dsilva/gitprojects/tenzing --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=/Users/david.dsilva/gitprojects/tenzing --container-id bf03ac3cc33d13c6fcc88486049f00f21910a2bacfbc0842c62f71a0880b8a40 --log-level debug --log-format json --config /Users/david.dsilva/gitprojects/tenzing/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --skip-non-blocking-commands false --prebuild false --stop-for-personalization true --remote-env REMOTE_CONTAINERS_IPC=/tmp/vscode-remote-containers-ipc-4a3b608b-6e6c-401b-ae7b-85bc74c3e421.sock --remote-env SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/vscode-ssh-auth-4a3b608b-6e6c-401b-ae7b-85bc74c3e421.sock --remote-env REMOTE_CONTAINERS=true --mount-workspace-git-root true --terminal-columns 205 --terminal-rows 22 --dotfiles-target-path ~/dotfiles
[15478 ms] 
[15479 ms] 
[15484 ms] Port forwarding connection from 51128 > 33077 > 33077 in the container.
[15484 ms] Start: Run in container: /root/.vscode-server/bin/6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794/node -e 
[15537 ms] @devcontainers/cli 0.50.0. Node.js v16.17.1. darwin 22.1.0 arm64.
```

I can provide more of the logs if it's useful / my `devcontainer.json` / `compose.yml` / `settings.json`. I've been stuck on this for a little under a week and any hindsight on the issue would be greatly appreciated.